# Feature Request: Desktop Notifications

Tags: feature-request

Right now, we receive Stack Exchange notifications in the subtle “inbox.” Wouldn’t it be great to receive Desktop Notifications, considering this is an Apple QA?

Answer (score 2):

You can already receive desktop notifications with this app: https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x

It's not integrated with the notification center, but has growl support.

Or, you can use this other app https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x

Comment: Desktop Notifications specifically is a Notification Center feature. I would rather have it integrated.

Comment: @duci9y Considering that StackExchange is not only a Apple Q&A but also various other systems sharing the same codebase, I doubt there wil be a huge push for an Apple only feature to be implemented when there is a huge amount of other new feature that need to be completed.

Comment: Many Stack Exchange users use OS X to access the site. And it is a very simple but important feature.